# No Ethernet on MacBook Pro

Tags: ethernet

Have had MAcBook for about 4 yrs., this is first time I can recall using ethernet, and computer doesn't see it.

SD card reader quit working some time ago but USB is okay.

Ran diagnostic getting 4MEM/9/40000000 0:0x7f1c1390 error.

[image: My Networks]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  It's helpful if you provide the exact model of your MacBook Pro as well as the version of OS X you are running.  Also, in Terminal, issue the command `system_profiler SPNetworkDataType`.  You will get a bunch of info; look for the section that says "Ethernet" and paste that info to your question.  As for your error - that's a memory issue, so you could be having two separate issues here.

Answer (score 2):

Under the list of network interfaces on the left that you have in the screenshot, press the + (plus) icon. For Interface, select Ethernet. Press Create. Does that work?